# chef 12 configuration error - object not found while running knife cli

Tags: linux, chef-infra, knife

Running chef 12 on Ubuntu 14.1. Using self signed certs to setup the server, when I try to run knife commands from my client it fails with following error. Any operation has same error. chef server logs do not have any errors or info during the query.

knife config

```
[root@ip-10-233-2-40 ~]# cat ~/.chef/knife.rb 
log_level                :debug
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'admin'
client_key               '/root/.chef/admin.pem'
validation_client_name   'dev'
validation_key           '/root/.chef/dev-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://chef.example.com/organizations/dev'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/root/.chef/syntax_check_cache'

root@ip-10-233-2-177:~/ssl-certs# chef-server-ctl status
run: bookshelf: (pid 1092) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1064) 1998s
run: nginx: (pid 6140) 723s; run: log: (pid 1063) 1998s
run: oc_bifrost: (pid 1077) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1058) 1998s
run: oc_id: (pid 1091) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1061) 1998s
run: opscode-erchef: (pid 1090) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1066) 1998s
run: opscode-expander: (pid 1076) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1060) 1998s
run: opscode-expander-reindexer: (pid 1096) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1059) 1998s
run: opscode-solr4: (pid 1075) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1057) 1998s
run: postgresql: (pid 1085) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1056) 1998s
run: rabbitmq: (pid 1062) 1998s; run: log: (pid 1046) 1998s
run: redis_lb: (pid 6124) 723s; run: log: (pid 1065) 1998s


 [root@ip-10-233-2-40 ~]# knife environment create staging
    ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:325:in `stream_check': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:199:in `read_body'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:499:in `rescue in format_rest_error'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:497:in `format_rest_error'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:459:in `humanize_http_exception'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:418:in `humanize_exception'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:409:in `rescue in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:400:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:203:in `run'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:142:in `run'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/knife:54:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/knife:54:in `<main>'`enter code here`
```

**Update**

```
[root@ip-10-233-2-40 ~]# knife client list -VV
INFO: Using configuration from /root/.chef/knife.rb
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONOutput#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_request
DEBUG: Signing the request as admin
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_request
DEBUG: Using 10.233.0.182:3128 for proxy
DEBUG: Initiating GET to https://chef.example.com/organizations/dev/clients
DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
DEBUG: Accept: application/json
DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: admin
DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2015-10-21T17:40:17Z
DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: m/vlWcZBPE7XUN7qhX6t/T9hXTT+2x/JehpOYq6My1ffEID6n+U+Xc+lHWto
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: Lq4ZEfNT1ltZkkYZ9Ii8EoF3eajUQmb2buwKMWae3yvxrZ5rgllJPf5q4gy3
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: IEqUUst+KzmoRHCiC1LeYxKXy+oeo45F4Vw4xHlOWgS0piqXfrmXnkrxs8Um
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: ZDqdLvcQ10WjoW9Wz4F2+fRh/BdRHjwMF80LVPwrtylf+GbdIhmCU3xxVvOq
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: w1Z2p03UcpRfMZy1pQV59A0Y3yv57Db5n3PJdjD9TlitNK++/HXcqO3IfO2U
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: 0QbZYZaeGSkJw0ArQDeffnjbpzAhSXhUfbs+in9tRg==
DEBUG: HOST: chef.example.com:443
DEBUG: X-Ops-Server-API-Version: 1
DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: 6a00a52a-7eeb-43d6-920d-fffc685c1b2a
DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!': 404 "Not Found" (Net::HTTPServerException)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:128:in `value'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:915:in `connect'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http/basic_client.rb:65:in `request'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:266:in `block in send_http_request'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:298:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:296:in `loop'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:296:in `retrying_http_errors'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:260:in `send_http_request'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:143:in `request'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:110:in `get'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/api_client_v1.rb:198:in `list'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife/client_list.rb:38:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:405:in `block in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:404:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:203:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:142:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/knife:54:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/knife:54:in `<main>'


[root@ip-10-233-2-40 ~]# telnet chef.example.com 443
Trying 10.233.2.177...
Connected to chef.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: run knife with `-VV` to get more insight on what query give the error. According to your machine names, does `chef.example.com` properly resolve to 10.223.2.177 ? Is there not another webserver (let's say apache) already listening on port 443 and preventing nginx to bind to it ?

Comment: @Tensibai - no other webserver is running on the node, it resolve to the right ip.  -VV is helpful,

Comment: Configure no_proxy option in knife.rb,  your proxy has no clue about chef.example.com (sounds legit as example.com is reserved for internal use) and so can't redirect to it....

Comment: @Tensibai - You nailed it.. Thanks a lot. It is a proxy issue.